# windows 10 custom title bar color

Tags: windows-10, titlebar

Microsoft Apps such as Word, Excel use custom colors in the window title bar.  IntelliJ and BeyondCompare have chosen similar colored icons so to takes a few more of **MY** cycles to select the correct window when I am changing tasks.

Is there a way to tailor installed applications to have a specific title bar color perhaps using registry entries and themes. This would speed up task switches which I do continuously in development mode.

As a second choice, I am not adverse to creating an IntelliJ plugin that would zap the color if that would do the job but am not sure if there is a way to easily zap the title bar color in the Windows-10 API.